# Display a custom field in WooCommerce email notifications for admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, email-notifications

I installed Checkout Field Editor on my wordpress site. I created the custom field. However, using the following code, the pcustomer field appears both in the "new order" email that arrives to me and to the customer. Instead I want it to come exclusively to me. I tried to edit the code, but it still doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3 );
function custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    $fields['meta_key'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Label' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, 'meta_key', true ),
    );
    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since WooCommerce 3, your code is a bit outdated, with some mistakes Try the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3 );
function custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    $meta_key = '_meta_key1'; // <= Here define the correct meta key
    $meta_value = $order->get_meta( $meta_key1 );
    
    if ( ! empty( $meta_value1 ) ) {
        $fields[ $meta_key1 ] = array(
            'label' => __( 'My label 1', "text-domain' ),
            'value' => $meta_value1,
        );
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Now to restrict the code **only to admin email  notifications**, you will use `$sent_to_admin` argument variable as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3 );
function custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    if ( $sent_to_admin ) {
        $meta_key1 = '_meta_key1'; // <= Here define the correct meta key
        $meta_value1 = $order->get_meta( $meta_key1 );
        
        if ( ! empty( $meta_value1 ) ) {
            $fields[ $meta_key1 ] = array(
                'label' => __( 'My label 1', "text-domain' ),
                'value' => $meta_value1,
            );
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

This time this custom field will not be displayed on customer email notifications.

> **Note**:

- `$order->id`is uncorrect  since WooCommerce 3. use instead `$order->get_id()`.
- WordPress `get_post_meta()` function can be replace by WooCommerce `WC_Data` `get_meta()` method.